# mysql query for items with multiple conditions (item options)

Tags: mysql, database

What I like to achieve is
a: display all Items that are in **all** of the selected category's
b: return / update the category list with category's available based on selection

I like items to be stored and be found by use of the adjacency list model or nested sets.
I've experimented with both and may use advice what would be the best for this case.

Currently I'm using (testing with) the adjacency list model like this:

```
items:  
ID | item_name
====================
1  | car
2  | boat
3  | bike

items_cats: (many to many)
iid | cid
====================
1   |  1
1   |  2
1   |  4
1   |  7

2   |  1
2   |  3
2   |  4
2   |  7

3   |  1
3   |  3
3   |  4
3   |  8

categorys: 
ID | cat_name  | parent_id
========================
1  | safety:   |   0    (0 = no parent)
2  | safe      |   1
3  | dangerous |   1

4  | fun:      |   0
5  | a bit     |   5
6  | boring    |   5
7  | funny     |   5
8  | cool      |   5
```

So its no problem to get items based on cid but how would you:

1st: selection:
1- Display all items who have cat id: cid 7 (funny)?
2- return (array/object) of all category's who have items that also contain cid 7?
Would you all do this in one query or would two be more efficient?

2nd: selection:
3- Display all items who have cat id: cid 7 and **also** contain cat id '3' (dangerous)
4- return (array/object) of all category's who have items that contain cid 7 and cid 3?

For selecting on multiple category's I found the flowing solution. Is this a good one and would there be to gain any performance especially when the number of category's grow?

```
    SELECT 
      DISTINCT t1.product_id, t1.category_id
    FROM 
      items_cats t1   
    INNER JOIN
       items_cats t1b 
       ON t1.iid =t1b.iid 
    WHERE
      t1.cid=3 AND
      t1b.cid=7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a list of all items that have category ID = 7, start with your many:many table

```
select
      i.item_name
   from
      items_cat ic
         join items i
            on ic.iid = i.id
   where
      ic.cid = 7
```

to get all categories associated with any item that has the category ID of 7, you can expand from the first and get categories associate for those item IDs

```
select DISTINCT
      ic2.cid,
      c.cat_name,
      coalesce( CatParent.cat_name, "" ) as ParentCategoryName
   from
      ( select distinct ic.iid
           from items_cat ic
           where ic.cid = 7 ) QualifiedItems

         JOIN items_cat ic2
            on QualifiedItems.iid = ic2.iid
            JOIN categorys c
               on ic2.cid = c.id
               LEFT JOIN categorys CatParent
                  on c.parent_id = CatParent.ID
```

For 3 and 4, it would be similar, but to qualify BOTH (or anytime, more than one), you need to apply an OR, a GROUP BY and make sure that the final count matches those you were trying to qualify

```
select
      i.item_name
   from
      items_cat ic
         join items i
            on ic.iid = i.id
   where
      ic.cid in( 3, 7 )
   group by 
      i.item_name
   having
      count(*) = 2
```

So you can better understand and apply these principles, I'll leave the last one for you to try and implement... If you really get stuck, let me know... :)